# Visualizing very large network graph with colored source node

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a large dataframe(df) with Weight ,Source Node, target columns.
This is small sample of the df:

| SourceNode | target | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 176890 | 657826 | 201 |
| 136578 | 589231 | 300 |
| 143873 | 457139 | 50 |
| 134589 | 892147 | 550 |
| 198345 | 678931 | 350 |
| 112443 | 525188 | 600 |
| 336128 | 689313 | 1500 |

Source node and target column are object and weight is int data type.
I am trying to create a large network graph which shows the connectivity from source node to target column (unidirect) and the edge need to reflect the weight value( like by stronger bigger connection).
I am getting very compact graph. I replaced kamada_kawai_layout with spring_layout and circular_layout but non have worked, Any suggestion how to make it larger and more spread?

I am also want to add the source node color as well

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx


G= nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source = 'SourceNode', target='target' , edge_attr= 'Weight')

edges = G.edges.data()

pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)
edge_width = [e[2]['Weight']/1000 for e in edges]
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True) # draw nodes (and edges!)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, width=edge_width)
```

I am adding this line for SourceNode color , but it doesn't work :

```
color_map = ['blue' if node == df['target'] else 'black' for node in G]        
graph = nx.draw_networkx(G,pos, node_color=color_map)
```

I am very new to python. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have, or can you install, matplotlib? NetworkX depends on other software for visualization. Try something like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

# These lines probably aren't necessary on most machines
# import matplotlib
# matplotlib.use("TKAgg")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Source": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    "Target": [2, 3, 3, 4, 5],
    "Weight": [5, 2, 3, 6, 1]
})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df,
    source = 'Source',
    target='Target' ,
    edge_attr= 'Weight'
)

edges = G.edges.data()
edge_width = [e[2]["Weight"] for e in edges]

pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos = pos, with_labels = True, width = edge_width)
plt.show()

nodes = G.nodes
color_map = ["blue" if node < 3 else "green" for node in nodes]
nx.draw(G, pos = pos, with_labels = True, width = edge_width, node_color = color_map)
plt.show()
```

To make more sparse, you might just need to make the window bigger and/or everything else smaller:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
figsize = fig.get_size_inches()
nx.draw(
    G, pos = pos, with_labels = True,
    node_size = 100, 
    width = [ew/10 for ew in edge_width],
    node_color = color_map,
    ax = ax
)
fig.set_size_inches(figsize * 2)
fig.show()
```

#### Other Options

For visualizing large graphs, have you tried [Gephi](https://gephi.org/)? From the NetworkX [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#drawing):

> NetworkX provides basic functionality for visualizing graphs, but its main goal is to enable graph analysis rather than perform graph visualization. In the future, graph visualization functionality may be removed from NetworkX or only available as an add-on package.